# How do I avoid repeating the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query in below. I select column with some conditions. In the case when statement, if the when clause is true then I select column which defines in when clause so I repeat the same query.

How can I prevent this in below and also Do you have an idea about prevent repeat the same query in sql.

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT
        TOP 1
        wo.licence_plate
    FROM
        work wo
        JOIN work_order ds ON wo.pk_id = ds.fk_work_order_id
        JOIN parameter par  ON ds.status = par.code
    WHERE
        par.id = 1246
        AND
        par.code = 5
        AND
        wo.customer_id = cus.pk_id
        AND
        wo.delivery_date > DATEADD( day, -7, GETDATE() )
)
THEN 
(
    SELECT
        TOP 1 wo.licence_plate
    FROM
        work wo (NOLOCK)
        JOIN work_order ds ON wo.pk_id = ds.fk_work_order_id
        JOIN parameter par  ON ds.status = par.code
    WHERE
        par.parameter_group_id = 1246
        and
        par.code = 5
        and
        wo.customer_id = cus.pk_id
        and
        wo.delivery_date > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
) ELSE ' ' END
    as result
FROM
    customer cus
```

Comment: *"In the case when statement"* It's a `CASE` *expression*.

Comment: The query inside the exists clause and the query following `THEN` do _not_ appear to be the same to me at all.  Please explain this.

Comment: I agree with @Tim , in the first query you reference `work`, `work_order` and `parameter`, and in the latter `tbl_asx_work_order`, `tbl_asx_work_order_delivery_status` and `tbl_par_parameter` and spam `NOLOCK` against them (a bad habit as I presume you don't know what it does). As they are different you need to define them both.

Comment: Put the query result in a variable. Then, if your variable is null, replace it with empty sting.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) And if you understand NOLOCK and accept the consequences, at least use current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This will return `' '`, if the record does not exist.

```
SELECT ISNULL(SELECT
        1 wo.licence_plate
    FROM
        dbo.tbl_asx_work_order wo
        JOIN tbl_asx_work_order_delivery_status ds ON wo.pk_id = ds.fk_work_order_id
        JOIN tbl_par_parameter par ON ds.status = par.code
    WHERE
        par.parameter_group_id = 1246
        and
        par.code = 5
        and
        wo.customer_id = cus.pk_id
        and
        wo.delivery_date > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()), ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `OUTER APPLY` for this.
Then use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` to default into an empty string if nothing matched.

```
SELECT cus.*
, COALESCE(oa.licence_plate, '') AS licence_plate
FROM customer cus
OUTER APPLY (
 SELECT TOP 1 wo.licence_plate
 FROM work wo
 JOIN work_order ds ON wo.pk_id = ds.fk_work_order_id
 JOIN [parameter] par ON ds.status = par.code
 WHERE wo.customer_id = cus.pk_id
  AND par.id = 1246 AND par.code = 5 
  AND wo.delivery_date > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
) oa;
```